# raw-loader and vue3 - dependency was not found

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, raw-loader

I want to import a .md file as text in my vue3 component. Like this

```
import test from "!raw-loader!./assets/test.md";
```

And I'm using (as you can see) `raw-loader`.

I also have this in my `vue.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: (config) => {
        config.module
            .rule("raw")
            .test(/\.md$/)
            .use("raw-loader")
            .loader("raw-loader")
            .end();
    },
};
```

But when I start my development server with `npm run serve` I get his error:

```
This dependency was not found:

* !raw-loader!./assets/test.md in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save !raw-loader!./assets/test.md
```

How can I solve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `!raw-loader!` isn't needed if you configured a loader